# French character é is printing as � in jhipster thymeleaf template

Tags: utf-8, thymeleaf, jhipster

I am using Jhipster application email functionality to send mail on user creation. When sending mail in French the character like é is printing wrongly.
These characters are coming from standard `messages_fr.properties` file.

Obviously its encoding issue but both in email template html and java code we are setting encoding as UTF-8, which should display this correctly.

While debugging I found that in `MailService.java` class, content loaded by the SpringTemplateEngine's process method have already  loaded the character wrongly before setting the encoding as UTF-8.

My code:

```
String content = templateEngine.process("activationEmail", context);
```

Looks like I know the root cause of it but as it is Spring's internal API class, I don't know how to fix this issue.

Comment: Looks like you tagged this wrong. This should be tagged Java, not PHP.

Comment: @ryantxr - updated the tags. Thanks.

Comment: Usually, it's a problem of file encoding *.properties, make sure your editor or IDE has not changed the file

Comment: @ Gael : hmmm..... I think you have pointed the exact root cause.I just checked that STS IDE is setting all the .properties text files in ISO and not in UTF by default. I changed the encoding to UTF-8 and tested. It's is working fine now.... Thanks a lot!!!

Answer (score 0):

As Gael pointed I found that the exact root cause of issue is that STS is changing the encoding of .properties files to ISO by default. Changing the file back to UTF-8 is the solution of this issue. Thanks Gael for pointing to this direction.